# JSP scripting elements

Tags: jsp

I am actually trying to learn JSP. My question is related to scripting elements. In particular in JSP page I found this:

```
--%><%--
--%><%@ include file="/common.jsp" %><%--
--%><%@ page errorPage="/ck/bs/error/startError.jsp" %><%--
--%><%@ page import="browser.client.jsp.Session" %><%--
--%><%--
```

Can anyone tell me what are "--%><%--" at beginning and end each line code?
Thanks a lot!

Comment: Where did you find that? `<%-- comment --%>` is a comment. But what you posted is invalid code.

Answer (score 1):

```
<%--  this scriptlet is use for comment in JSP   --%>
```

You didn't get it proper so that you confused.